# How to remove an element from a <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the code:

```
<tr class="active" aria-selected="true" data-row-id="3">
```

I am using:  $("tr").removeClass("active"); to remove the "active" class which works perfectly but I also need to set aria-selected="true" to "false", this is for a data-table selection in a modal.  Any help will be most helpful,

Thank you!

Comment: Look for `jQuery.attr` method...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to update element attribute.

```
$('tr').attr('aria-selected','false');
```

Comment: That does the asthetics part, odd thing is when I open the modal, make a select, close it, everything clears, but if I select another option, the previous selection gets chosen also, not sure why, but thank you for your answer it helped a lot!

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#modalAdd').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
             $("tr").removeClass("active");
             $("tr").attr("aria-selected","false");
             $(".select-box").attr("checked", false);
            });
        </script>

Comment: @TyeLucas `$('tr')` would target all the `tr` in the page..... you should target certain `tr` using class or any other mechanism

Answer (score 1):

Thank you I changed my code to:

```
            $('#modalAdd').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $(".active").attr("aria-selected","false");
            $(".active").removeClass("active");
            $(".select-box").attr("checked", false);
```